# Spring boot: Converting response to pojo

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing, converters

I am busy with an integration test. I have a struggle with converting the response body to the required entity data:

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("header_name", "header_value");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(fileToBeRead("file.xml"), headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/api", request, String.class);
```

how can I convert the the received json data to Java POJO.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use your POJO instead of `String.class` in the "post" method:
`ResponseEntity<MyPojo> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/api", request, MyPojo.class);`

or directly:
`MyPojo myPojo = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8081/api", request, MyPojo.class);`

If you have followed the standard Spring Boot setup for your tests, then the Resttemplate is automatically configured with sane defaults to deserialize your POJO (using the Jackson library most likely).